# TextBox binding to a processed string

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, textbox

I've got a problem with textbox 'Text' binding. here's the code:

```
<TextBox Padding="2"
    AcceptsReturn="True"
    AcceptsTab="True"
    Name="txtCmd"
    Text="{Binding CommandText, 
                   Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

and here's the VM property:

```
private string _CommandText;
public string CommandText
{
    get
    {
        return this._CommandText;
    }
    set
    {
        if(!(value == this._CommandText))
        {
            this._CommandText = value;
            if (this._CommandText.IndexOf("\r\n") > -1)
            {
                ParseCommand(this._CommandText)
                this._CommandText = "";
            }
            base.OnPropertyChanged("CommandText");
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is: when I press enter in the textbox, ParseCommand calls and does whatever it has to do, also, _CommandText will be set to (""), but it does not affect the textbox.text value, I mean, next time when enter is pressed, still there are some '\r\n' in the _CommandText !

is there anything I do wrong? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Next time you press enter you *create* the `\r\n`.

Comment: H.B.: I've added        'this._CommandText = "";' so it should clear the TextBox, shouldn't it? each time I press enter the number of \r\n grow !!!

Comment: Well that's something else, but you certaily should expect one every time.

Comment: H.B: yes I expect just one! but I get more!

Comment: I have been able to reproduce this error, but am unable to diagnose a solution.  It happens when the TextBox is multi-line and the user hits 'return' when the TextBox is empty.  This action retains the line-feed/carriage return and moves the cursor to another line!  Weird.  No answer though.  I am assuming this has to do with some sort of quirk in the TextBox.  The OP's property code is ok, save for the ommission of Environment.NewLine and String.Empty...

Comment: yes Garry, this is what I get. when the textbox has something in it, works fine, but if it's empty problem shows up.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but one of the higher ups should retag the question because it's most likely a multi-line TextBox issue, and MVVM is a red-herring.

Comment: yep, and I'm really confused!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be better off handling this differently. You do not really need to bind the text as you do not want to synchronize data but process input, so using input events might be a better idea.

This could be coupled with commanding and the [Blend SDK's](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10801) `Interactivity`, e.g.

```
<TextBox Padding="2">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <t:KeyDownTrigger Key="Return">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ProcessCommandCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TextBox}}" />
        </t:KeyDownTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Where KeyDownTrigger is defined like this:

```
public class KeyDownTrigger : TriggerBase<TextBox>
{
    public Key Key { get; set; }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += new System.Windows.Input.KeyEventHandler(AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown -= AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown;
    }

    void AssociatedObject_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key)
        {
            InvokeActions(null);
        }
    }
}
```

And the command would be something like the following:

```
private readonly Command _ProcessCommandCommand = new Command(p =>
    {
        var tb = (TextBox)p;
        var command = tb.Text;
        // <Process command>
        tb.Clear();
    });
public Command ProcessCommandCommand { get { return _ProcessCommandCommand; } }
```

*(`Command` is what people like to call `RelayCommand`, a generic implementation of `ICommand` that uses functions passed in the constructor)*

Comment: I will try your solution. But I still have this question: What's wrong with my own code? Is this a problem with .NET Framework TextBox control? or what?

Comment: I just finished testing your solution H.B. works perfect. Thank you very much. (although I have a little problem with Tab key which I believe I can solve it :)

Comment: Hello H.B nice solution but i have small concern in solution, now command is tightly coupled with textbox. We can use converter to handle the scenario to clear the Textbox.

Comment: @H.B. I posted the problem to ms.connect and apparently this is a problem with .net, it will be solved in next version hopefully, http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/672240/binding-doesnt-re-read-modified-value

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reason of this behavior of TextBox, but to solve you problem set _CommandText = null instead of "". Here is sample code.

```
private string _CommandText;
public string CommandText
{
    get
    {
        return this._CommandText;
    }
    set
    {
        if(!(value == this._CommandText))
        {
            this._CommandText = value;
            if (this._CommandText.Contains("\r\n"))
            {
                ParseCommand(this._CommandText)
                this._CommandText = null;
            }
            base.OnPropertyChanged("CommandText");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I checked the strategy of assigning 'null' and the result is the same.  This answer doesn't work.

Comment: @Firoz: The problem occurs only when adding a new line without any other text, it will insert the linebreak and not be able to clear it.